# Virtual Serial Port on Linux with Elfin EE-10

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I want to connect the UART-Port of our central heater to my ProxMox-Server (LXC - Debian) over Web with Virtual Serial Port.

I bought this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000945033185.html and connected it to the central heater and is reachable in the local network.

Since I have never done something in this direction I'm not exactly sure how to set up the connection and I hope someone can help me.
In the Web-Interface of the device, I can set up different protocols ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkQBV.png)).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know more about what the heater is writing and expecting on the serial port. Did you select the right serial baud rate for it?

Have you read the EE-10 [IOT_Device_Series_Software_Funtion_20200623](http://www.hi-flying.com/elfin-ee10-elfin-ee11) guide (in Downloads tab)? One possibility for further debug is to select the telnetd mode and connect  from Linux with `telnet` to the IP address of the device, default port 23. (Ensure your Linux firewall allows this).

It seems it should ask for login and password, as in the web page. Then you might get an `EPORT>` prompt which is the EE-10 cli. Enter `Exit` to enter transparent mode when what you type is sent directly to the heater, and what you see comes from the heater.

Comment: The heater need 8N1 with 9600 baud. But I haven't even managed to get a connection with the EE-10. My goal is to use this https://github.com/horchi/linux-p4d daemon but not via local COM-Port but one on the local network. I have read the guide, but it they only use some "unknown" Windows-Software.

Comment: If you put the device on your internal network and you have a dhcp server, it should acquire a IP address. You can use this address in your browser to connect to the GUI you show in the image. I thought you had done that to get the image.

Comment: Yes, I did that and have an IP-Address. But I still don't know how to set up an virtual COM-Port that connects to the EE-10.

Comment: Not sure about the goal you are after, but `socat` is often used to join a network connection to a serial port (pty).

Comment: Thanks I will look into socat. My goal is nothing difficult, the heater is in the cellar and the server it should be connected to is on the second floor, so it is not possible to connect it with an cable.